# Инициализация свойств класса php в PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Добрый день.
Подскажите кто располагает информацией. Когда в среде PHPstorm в аргументы конструктора ставишь новые переменные и нажимаешь alt + Enter среда дает выбрать в появившемся меню инициализацию свойств класса. Проблема в том что подставляется  private. В более старой версии пхпшторма появлялось диалоговое окно в котором можно было выбрать из трех возможных private, public, protected. Не могу найти в настройках где включить появление этого окна.
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Из коробки это сделать невозможно, но ничто не мешает вам написать свой собственный плагин.

Чтобы убедиться посмотрите в настройках

Settings->Editor->Intentions->Initialize fields

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо за информацию!